# Does "stalemate" collocate with "cause" and "issue"?

Tags: collocation

Does the following sentence sound right, as far as style is concerned?

"His behaviour will cause a stalemate in this issue"

Please don`t hesitate and suggest any better-sounding collocations, if you know any.

Comment: For your sentence in isolation, 'on' or 'for' are idiomatic (AmE).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more natural to me to say that his behavior will bring about a stalemate.  But as you can tell from my spelling, that's a US English reaction.

Answer (score 0):

A "stalemate" is a term of art in chess, applying to a configuration of pieces in which one player has no legal moves.  This often arises when a king not in check has no moves that don't place it in check.  The rules dictate that the game cannot progress to a conclusion, and it is thus a draw.  The term has come to mean any kind of a deadlock that precludes resolution of a problem.

A stalemate applies to the proceedings, either a literal game of chess or some figurative game like contract negotiations or parliamentary maneuvers.  Perhaps a better use of prepositions would be to reserve "in" for the game and "on" or "about" for the particular sticking point:

> His stance on the minimum wage in the current negotiations for a new
>   labor contract will cause a stalemate.

As you note, this is a matter of style, and your original sentence is perfectly understandable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does "A stalemate in this issue" sound natural for you? Or perhaps "A stalemate with this issue" sounds better?

Comment: Also there is one thing I cannot understand in your answer, as far as syntax is concerned: 

Why did you write "A stalemate applies to the proceedings, either a literal game of chess or some figurative game like..." and not "A stalemate applies to the proceedings, >OF< either a literal game of chess or some figurative game like...".  

Was that a typo?

Comment: @IGO "A stalemate on" or "a stalemate about" sounds better to me, but remember that this is a matter of style.  There's no need for "of" after "proceedings."  "a literal game ... or some figurative game" is a compound appositive directly renaming "proceedings."